# Modify Regular Expression to not match if a word is present

Tags: java, python, regex

```
myRe = re.compile(r"(ALTER TABLE\s*\n*\t*)(.*)(\s*\n*\t*ADD\s*\n*\t*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\s+\n*?\t*?)(.*)")
newline = myRe.sub(r"EXEC osp_norm_ext_col_add '\4','\2','\6'", newline)
```

I have designed the above regex to alter statements like:

```
ALTER TABLE post_tran ADD ext_acq_ref_num VARCHAR (12) NULL
```

However, I do not want to change the above statement if it has the word `CONSTRAINT` after `ADD`, ie,

```
ALTER TABLE post_tran ADD CONSTRAINT ext_acq_ref_num VARCHAR (12) NULL
```

I tried using the lookahead operator but I'm confused because in that case group captures return empty.

please help!

Comment: Is checking for `CONSTRAINED` word in your query string by searching for substring an option? I'd be somewhat more efficient, since lookahead operations are quite heavy

Comment: I'm just wondering why you would use `\s*\n*\t*`, when `\s` covers spaces, tabs and line breaks.

Comment: Would `re.compile=r"(ALTER\s+TABLE)\s+(\w+)\s+(ADD)\s+(?!CONSTRAINT)(\w*)(\s+)(.*)"` work out for you?

Comment: I'm using python 2.3. So the /s doesn't cover newline or tabs,I tried.

Comment: Buld0zzr, I didn't get you. The regex should not compare the string if there's an ADD followed by CONSTRAINT. In cases, where ADD is followed by any other word, the regex should be able to detect the pattern.

Comment: That's why I added the negative lookahead `(?!CONSTRAINT) `

Comment: Thanks a lot LukStroms! You made my day! This regex works like a charm.